# Created trigger in MySql, works on localhost but not on server

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have fired the trigger query it works on my localhost but not on the server, don't give any error details.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the trigger was created on the server? And can you please add code as text rather than useless image.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `BingooTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO page_follow(user_id,page_id,created_at,updated_at) VALUES (new.id,324,new.created_at,new.updated_at);
     
END

Above query works on localhost but not on the server

Comment: Even at 400x magnification the images in the question are impossible to read. DID you set delimiters?AND did you check the trigger was created on the server?

Comment: If it doesn't work on the server it's not because of the code.

Comment: used delimiters too but not working, the trigger was not created on the server. Only shows "error" popup but no error details